# How to find the value of one column that corresponds to the max of another in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'm sure this has been asked and answered elsewhere, but I'm having trouble expressing the question succinctly. So take a simplified table:

```
ID     Year     Name
--------------------
1      2015     A
1      2014     B
1      2016     C
2      2011     D
2      2002     E
2      2014     F
```

I want to run a query that returns the Name that corresponds with the most recent (highest) Year for every ID, so:

```
ID     Name
-----------
1      C
2      F
```

I assume there's some WITH/AS statement involved, a GROUP BY, a MAX(), maybe a view? I'm not sure though. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

A Postgres specific solution using `distinct on()`

```
select distinct on (id) id, name
from the_table 
order by id, name desc;
```

With standard SQL this would be done using a window function:

```
select id, name
from (
  select id, name, 
         max(name) over (partition by id) as max_name
  from the_table
) t 
where name = max_name;
```

The `distinct on` solution is typically faster than the one using window functions, but it is not portable.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c4e74/1

Comment: Where does the year come in here (in the solution using DISTINCT ON())? That is, shouldn't I want to sort it by year somehow? In my actual example there are many more columns than these, so how would it know which to sort by?

Comment: @StephenSmith: well, your expected output only showed id and name as the output columns, so that's why I used. But in both solutions you can add as many other columns as you want. The first one has to be sorted by `id, name desc` as the first sort criteria. You can add sort columns after those as you like.

Comment: You'd add `year desc` to the `ORDER BY` to do what you want.